# Rhapsody: Get Selected Menu Item

Tags: c#, rhapsody

I would like to have one helper program that holds behaviour of two custom menus that grouped together:

For example : `MyHelper` menu has two sub-menus: `Helper Program` and `Helper Help`

Is it possible to get the selected menu item the user has chosen, using Rhapsody API?